# MSI installer finishes succesfully but no files are copied to the installation path

Tags: windows, windows-7, msi

We have a MSI installer that we cannot install in one Windows 7. The whole process finishes OK but when you go to program installation path there is nothing in there. It didn't even creates the main installation folder. I tried changing the path, disable UAC, no anti-virus. No luck. I run this machine as administrator. This is the only Windows7 that gives that problem.

The MSI installation log says: Installation success or error status: 0. If anybody wants to see the whole log please say and will try to upload it somewhere.

Here is the link to ProcMon screenshot > installation point when it supposedly finish transferring files to ProgramFiles x86.

[image]

Comment: You should use Process Monitor: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon and see what activity you can capture (look for msiexec.exe)

Comment: I run process explorer but couldn't see any abnormal activity. Could you please share where where would you look at?

Comment: You should run Process Monitor, not Process Explorer. You will be able to see msiexec.exe actually copying the files, creating the folders,... if you can't, you should at least be able to see if there is an "access denied" error, or something like that.

Comment: Sorry, silly mistake. I run Process Monitor and then pointed to the MSI installer only and I cannot see any ACCESS DENIED messages. The only ones that got my attention are "FILE NOT FOUND" or "FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS". I will edit the post and attach a screenshot if you'd like to have a quick look and let me know what you think.

Comment: Maybe run the MSI with verbose logging `msiexec /i {yourmsi.msi} /l*v log.txt` and see what gets output. Its usually a lot of output though.

Comment: Thanks, already done it and don't find it very useful in this particular case. If you want to see it I can send it to you.